# How does Java/JVM handle cycle import?

Tags: java, import, include, cycle

C/C++ will generate an cycle include error if headers are included circularly.
Python will generate an cycle import error if imports are circular.

Since Java/JVM never generate this kind of errors, how does Java/JVM handle cycle import in its implementation?

Comment: The Java *compiler* compiles both source files at the same time, so it knows both and can handle the cycle.

Comment: C/C++/Python import header files;  Java does not have header files, so no circular inclusions.  Java's import statement is effectively just syntactic sugar to avoid having to put the full package name with every class-name throughout the code.